# SwiftUI on MacOS: Detect Focus Change and force Focus Change programaticly

Tags: macos, keyboard, swiftui, focus

I want to detect a ***Focus Change*** and force a ***Focus Change***.
In this simple Example I want to detect, if a user klicks in one of the textfields.
On the other hand, I want so set the focus programaticly with a Button.

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @State private var textA = ""
  @State private var textB = ""

  @State private var focusableA = false
  @State private var focusableB = false

    var body: some View {
      VStack{
        HStack{
          TextField("Field A", text: $textA)
          .focusable(focusableA, onFocusChange: {f in print ("FocusChange A \(f)")})
          TextField("Field V", text: $textB)
          .focusable(focusableB, onFocusChange: {f in print ("FocusChange B \(f)")})
        }
        HStack{
          Button(action: {self.focusableA = true; self.focusableB = false }) 
          {Text("Set Focus to A")}
          Button(action: {self.focusableB = true; self.focusableA = false }) 
          {Text("Set Focus to B")
          }
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
  }
}
```

The Code above does not work, how can this be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to detect, if a user clicks in one of the textfields.

Here is an example for this

```
TextField("Title", text: boundText, onEditingChanged: { editing in
            if editing {
                print(">> start editing, got focus")
            } else {
                print(">> end editing, lost focus")
            }
        })
```

> I want so set the focus programaticly with a Button

SwiftUI itself does not give API for this for now. The `.focusable` gives *capability* to be focusable for views, which are not such by default (eg. Text), but not force-set focus.

Comment: Thanks, is there another way to set the Focus?